# Flexbox is not working as expected - items getting smaller

Tags: css, flexbox, grid

I got some issues when trying to make a stable 2 x 2 grid.

Idea:
I want to have a grid of icons, that always stays the same no matter how many items are inside (max. 4).

Therefor i created a block like this:

```
<div class="d-inline-flex align-items-center justify-content-start pl-2 flex-wrap">
    <div style="background-color: #00b319; flex: 1 0 50%; " class="order-0 p-1">
        <font-awesome-icon :icon="getIcon('addIcon')" :size="'sm'"
                           class="align-baseline" style="display: block; margin: auto;"></font-awesome-icon>
    </div>
    <div style="background-color: #ff0000; flex: 1 0 50%; " class="order-0 p-1">
        <font-awesome-icon :icon="getIcon('addIcon')" :size="'sm'"
                           class="align-baseline" style="display: block; margin: auto;"></font-awesome-icon>
    </div>
    <div style="background-color: #17a2b8; flex: 0 1 50%; " class="order-0 p-1" v-if="false">
        <font-awesome-icon :icon="getIcon('addIcon')" :size="'sm'"
                           class="align-baseline" style="display: block; margin: auto;"></font-awesome-icon>
    </div>
    <div style="background-color: #00b373; flex: 1 1 45%; " class="order-0 p-1" v-if="false">
        <font-awesome-icon :icon="getIcon('addIcon')" :size="'sm'"
                           class="align-baseline" style="display: block; margin: auto;" v-if="true"></font-awesome-icon>
    </div>
</div>
```

(Don't mind the `<font-awesome-icon>` tags - I create a Vuejs app here)

That works fine when I have 4 items inside.
But when I remove one, the whole container shrinks - removing another one -> it shrinks again.

[image: 4 items]
[image: 3 items]
[image: 2 items]

Is there a way to achieve that kind of grid in an responsive and flexible way?

Thank you!

Comment: You need to specify width on the parent element

Comment: @TeoDragovic does not work as expected - I introduced a wrapper div around the code you see above with defined width (in pixels) and it still grows/shrinks like before.

Comment: I suspect that behavior has something to do with you using `inline-flex`. Can you change it so it's `display: flex`? Without width on inline-flex container it will still behave like `span` tag and will not fill in wrapper if there is less content.

Comment: @TeoDragovic works! Thank you!